# How to customize moodle core files?

Tags: php, moodle

I would like to `customize view.php` file which is the core file of moodle, since modifying it in core is not good practice I would like to modify it from my theme,

By default there is a **cool theme**, I just copy pasted the course directory into it and Try to customize it but moodle is not recognizing my directory.

What is the procedure to do this kind of customization, I check this [link](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=237851) but unable to follow it since I don't understand. Can any one help me here about it?

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact that there are several view.php files, which one do you want to adapt?

Please note that you cannot simply overwrite for example course/view.php in your theme. You have to override the specific renderers, see https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overriding_a_renderer

Comment: I would like to customize the html structure of view course page.. How can I achieve this??

Comment: Guess you will have to override some functions of the core_course_renderer class, depending which output you want to change. See /course/renderer.php for all methods available here, so that you get a basic understanding how course page is rendered

Comment: Yes of course I tried, but when I check the files and functions it takes me in and in and in, got struck which one to render with

Comment: Is there any way to render `course/format/renderer.php` file??

Comment: Actually you can override course/view.php using custom scripts in Moodle (not to mention messing with the server configuration) but I agree that renderers are better for that.

Answer (score 0):

To override an url in Moodle you may use [custom scripts](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/customscripts). However if it's a matter of a renderer you should try overriding that first.

Comment: any way to render course/format/renderer.php file, since it is abstract class unable to do it. I would like to customize section_header method

Comment: As an example, download https://moodle.org/plugins/format_masonry and check renderer.php. You can do the ovverrides also in your theme, no need to create a custom course format